# Determine type without passing generic

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a class that gets extended and takes a generic type which itself takes a type:

`abstract class BaseClass<T : BaseT<U : BaseU>>`

Of course the code above, while it shows the structure of generics passed, is invalid, so I have to write it like this:

`abstract class BaseClass<T : BaseT<U>, U : BaseU>`

This means I have to write out both types:

`class MyClass : BaseClass<MyT, MyU>()`

Since `MyT` declares a type for `BaseT` to use, is there any way to get the type of `U` from `T` without being so verbose? I would like to just write `BaseClass<MyT>` and have it figure out that since `class MyT : BaseT<MyU>` it should expect the associated subtype of `U`, for any subtype of `BaseT`. Am I overthinking this? Is the correct answer just "write both generics in and stop complaining"?

Comment: `abstract class BaseClass<T : BaseT<out BaseU>>`

Comment: That was exactly what I needed! I just read up on `in`/`out`  recently, but didn't realize it would solve the issue here. Can you write up an answer explaining why this works so I can accept it?